# How to build K-means clusters in binary fashion?

Tags: python, binary, cluster-analysis, geospatial, k-means

I want to build K-means cluster for large geospatial data. In order to improve the performance, I have an idea to build clusters in binary fashion meaning, initially the data frame will be split into 2 clusters (eg: c1, c2), and the 1st cluster (c1) will be split down further into 2 (c3, c4), and cluster 2 will be split into (c5,c6). This way the number of levels can be given as an input to the function.. Any idea how this can be implemented in Python? Is there any inbuilt function or articles how this can be achieved?

Comment: Technically, you could just build your clusters recursively. But I would ask myself 1) Are you sure the k-means algorithm benefits from this (you would multiply ordo with log(N)) 2) Are you confident based on prior knowledge of the data that this yields the result you want?

Comment: Google says k-means is O(N) so your solution would be O(N log (N)), i.e. it would perform worse, unless I miss some information.